# Android: java.util.zip Not works, and jazzlib not works too

Tags: java, android, zip, unzip

I'm Developing a File Manager App. Now I want to make a UnZip feature, so I used java.util.zip class, but I failed. I should unzip Korean Characters / Japanese Characters, and Any other not English Alphabets. So I searched, and I found 'jazzlib' Library, so I attempted with it, but I still failed..

How to fix this problem? I think this is about encoding...

(Sorry for my bad english...)

Edit: 'failed' means the Korean Characters are broken like: 3�г� ���? ��~.xls

Comment: This should help you: [File names with Japanese characters turn to garbage when written to a zip file using java.util.zip.\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977711/file-names-with-japanese-characters-turn-to-garbage-when-written-to-a-zip-file-u)

Comment: @323go Did you mean Chilkat's Java Zip library?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not unzip special character with normal encoding., to solve this problem in eclipse you must change the vm arguments, i live in spain and i ahve the same problem i resolve put in the vm the following -Dfile.encoding=cp1252 with this i think you will soved your problem, because when you convert your code into a jar the new encoding is included.

Comment: but I'm in Android. How can I change the VM option?

Comment: Ummm i supose that you was programmming in eclipse with the add for android. But you have linked the solution.

Comment: Why this question is closed? Its still important for android. International characters are not unzipped in year 2014. Zip it on android device - his is only one way